# I get FileNotFound error while using psutil library

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, syntax-error, psutil

I'm trying to run and kill site.py python script every 5 minutes using webreset.py script.

webreset.py:

```
from psutil import Process, Popen
from time import sleep
pid = 0
while True:
    if pid:
        Process(pid).terminate()
    process = Popen('python3 site.py')
    pid = process.pid
    sleep(300)
```

But when I run webreset.py on Ubuntu 20.04, I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webreset.py", line 7, in <module>
    process = Popen('python3 site.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 1316, in __init__
    self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3 site.py'
```

I run the script using this command :

```
sudo python3 webreset.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the command and arguments.

```
process = Popen(['python3', 'site.py'])
```

Otherwise it is looking for a command with the filename "python3 site.py"

Answer (score 0):

using this:

```
Popen(['python3', 'site.py'])
```

instead of:

```
process = Popen('python3 site.py')
```

fixed my problem.